# Can someone explain localization with Sanity

Tags: next.js, localization, internationalization, sanity

I have a client that wants their website (next 14 / tailwind / sanity v3) in both English and Georgian, so my plan is to  follow [sanity's localization guide](https://www.sanity.io/docs/localization#c0d13d324c14) and trying to use their recommended [internationalized-array plugin](https://www.sanity.io/plugins/internationalized-array) but am running into issues.

I believe the plugin was added correctly // sanity.config.js

```
/**
 * This configuration is used to for the Sanity Studio that’s mounted on the `\app\studio\[[...index]]\page.tsx` route
 */

import {visionTool} from '@sanity/vision';
import {defineConfig} from 'sanity';
import {deskTool} from 'sanity/desk';
import {documentInternationalization} from '@sanity/document-internationalization';
import { internationalizedArray } from 'sanity-plugin-internationalized-array';

// Go to https://www.sanity.io/docs/api-versioning to learn how API versioning works
import {apiVersion, dataset, projectId} from './sanity/env';
import {schema} from './sanity/schema';

export default defineConfig({
  basePath: '/admin',
  projectId: 'asqrlfyx',
  dataset,
  // Add and edit the content schema in the './sanity/schema' folder
  title: 'Bokeria',
  apiVersion: "2023-11-11", 
  schema,
  plugins: [
    deskTool(),
    // Vision is a tool that lets you query your content with GROQ in the studio
    // https://www.sanity.io/docs/the-vision-plugin
    visionTool({defaultApiVersion: apiVersion}),
    documentInternationalization({
      supportedLanguages: [
        {id: 'ka', title: 'Georgian'},
        {id: 'en', title: 'English'}
      ],
      schemaTypes: ['author', 'blockContent', 'category', 'post', 'service']
    }),
    internationalizedArray({
      languages: [
        {id: 'en', title: 'English'},
        {id: 'ka', title: 'Georgian'}
      ],
      defaultLanguages: ['ka'],
      fieldTypes: ['string']
    }),
  ],
})
```

but I don't understand how to use internationlizedArrayString to create the fields for each item. Below is my current employee schema, and the sanity studio doesn't raise an error for "name" but for "title" and "alt" I get "Expect type string, got array".

```
import { defineField } from "sanity";

const employee = {

    name: 'employee',
    title: 'Employee',
    type: 'document',
    fields: [
        defineField({
            name: 'name',
            type: 'internationalizedArrayString',
        }),
        defineField({
            name: 'title',
            type: 'internationalizedArrayString',
        }),
        {
            name: 'slug', 
            title: 'Slug', 
            type: 'slug',
            options: { source: 'name'}
        },
        {
            name: 'image',
            title: 'Image',
            type: 'image',
            options: { hotspot: true },
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'alt',
                    title: 'Alt',
                    type: 'internationalizedArrayString',
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'information', 
            title: 'Information', 
            type: 'array',  
            of: [{ type: 'block'}], 
        },
    ],
}

export default employee
```

Can someone help me figure out how to use the plugin on simple string fields, as well as for the block content of "information"?

FYI I will provide my own translations so I don't need an extra translation plugin, etc for that.